# BULK INSERT from VARBINARY containing CSV file

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert, varbinary

I have a CSV file that needs to be `BULK INSERT`ed in my database.

---

The actual scheme is:

1. *Client* generates **file01.csv**
2. *Client* moves **file01.csv** into the shared folder **\\SERVERNAME\Sharing**, that points to **C:\Data** in the *Server*
3. *Client* tells database the file is called **file01.csv**
4. *Server* `BULK INSERT`s **C:\Data\file01.csv** into the final table
5. *Server* removes the **file01.csv** from its queue
   *(It'll be deleted later)*

---

The Windows shared folders are a bit buggy and unstable, so I want to make it a bit different:

1. *Client* generates **file01.csv**
2. *Client* inserts **file01.csv** in `VARBINARY(MAX)` column
3. *Server* simulates the **CSV** from the `VARBINARY` and `BULK INSERT`s it into the final table
   *(without generating any file in the server side)*

The only way I found to make the second option happen is:

3. *Server* generates **temp.csv** from the `VARBINARY` data
4. *Server* `BULK INSERT`s **temp.csv** into the final table
   *(It'll be deleted later)*

---

Is there a way to use a `VARBINARY` variable instead of a file in the `BULK INSERT`?

Or if it isn't possible, is there a better way to do this?

<sub>(Searched Google for a answer and found only how to read a `VARBINARY` value from a CSV file, so my question may be a duplicate)</sub>

Comment: If you are willing and able to allow the client to insert the .csv into a table with a varbinary column, why not let them insert it into either a staging table or the final table?

Comment: If you have SQL Server 2016 or later, why don't you try to use PolyBase where the external table can simple refer to the file location and apply the schema on read?

Comment: @Vinnie It's SQL Server 2012

Comment: @TabAlleman Using BCP? I dont have it on the client

Comment: Using whatever method you are proposing to use to insert the .csv into the varbinary.

Comment: I would use BLOB

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do what you describe is to create an SSIS package (or console app for that matter) with a script task that reads the Varbinary column into a single-column DataTable, parses into a "final-table-formatted" data table, and then does the bulk insert.   The whole process would be in-memory.

Comment: I don't want any other program running in the server, but how can I do this?

Comment: If you don't want any additional programs, you could write a CLR proc that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the varbinary(max) data into a [FileTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).  SQL Server would actually write the data to a local file, which you could then process with BULK INSERT.